# Proving an Inner Product on $\mathbb{C}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

> Let $\langle u, v\rangle = u^* \begin{bmatrix} 8 & -1 \\ -1 & 8 \end{bmatrix}$ $v$ be defined on $\mathbb{C}^2\times\Bbb C^2$. Prove, or disprove, that $\langle u, v\rangle$ is an inner product on $\Bbb C^2$.

According to my textbook (A First Course in Wavelets with Fourier Analysis, 2nd ed.), to prove something is an inner product, you need to prove positivity, conjugate symmetry, homogeneity, and additivity. I'm a bit stuck on the positivity part; I got $\langle u, u\rangle$ up to:

$$8|u_1|^2 - \bar{u}_1 u_2 + u_1 \bar{u}_2 - 8|u_2|^2.$$

Where should I go from here to show that this sum is greater than $0$? Thank you.

Comment: One way to prove positivity it to find the eigenvalues of the matrix.

Comment: You've calculated $\langle u,u\rangle$ wrongly. It should be $8|u_1|^2-\bar{u}_1u_2-u_1\bar{u}_2+8|u_2|^2$.

Comment: Hint: $\bar u_1 u_2 + u_1 \bar u_2 = 2 \operatorname{Re}(\bar u_1 u_2) \le 2 | \bar u_1 | \, | u_2 | = 2 | u_1 | \, | u_2 |$.